# SharePoint 2010 - 301 URL Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

My requirement is to implement 301 redirect. I have tried using URL Rewrite using iis and Web.config. But both iis & web.config is taking more size.

Kindly suggest the possibilities to implement 301 redirect in sharepoint 2010 without using iis & web.config.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have a whole lot of options here, but here are a few:

1) IIS URL Rewrite Module (I know you don't want this, but it is actually the best route) - http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-redirects-revisited-301-302/

2) Your own custom Http Handler - http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2007-redirect-solved-using-301-instead-of-302-redirects/ (applies to 2007, but with the modifications suggestion here it works: http://subashandsharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-301-instead-of-302-redirects-in.html)

3) Use JavaScript in page content to do it - https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/redirect-a-sharepoint-site-by-using-the-content-editor-web-part.aspx

4) Use the AdditionalPageHead delegate to create your own user control that does it (see http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/ for an example on that control).  And just use a Response.Redirect call.